# CodeIgniter: Dynamic menu using anchor

Tags: php, codeigniter, anchor

I am trying to make a dynamic navigation menu using the anchor function, like this:

```
<?
$nav_pages = array('prodouct'   => 'Products/Shop',
                    'about'    => 'About',
                    'contact'  => 'Contact',
                    'press' => 'Press'
                   );
?>
<header>
    <img src="img/my-logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <nav>   
        <?
        foreach($nav_pages as $link => $text){
            anchor($link, $text);
        }
        ?>
    </nav>
</header>
```

But this is the result:

```
<header><nav></nav></header>
```

Any idea why? (no errors are logged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `echo` in the loop is missing:

```
foreach($nav_pages as $link => $text){
    echo anchor($link, $text);
}
```